# Way of temporarily holding data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm after a bit of advice really. In an C# ASP.NET web solution I need to create a form whereby a user can add names and email addresses (an unlimited amount of times) and when they've finished adding these names and addresses they click a submit button and the 'records' then get posted to an SQL database.

So to summarise I need a wayto hold some data on the page that users can insert to and delete and I was after some advice on the best way to go about this. I did look at listviews and gridviews but they seem to suggest that I need a datasource to connect to and I don't have one the data purely needs to exist for the length of time that they have the form open and will be destroyed either when they submit to the database or cancel out of the form. I'm also presuming that it'll need to exist in an ajax update form as I don't want postbacks when they click to add a name/password.

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: This probably isn't using any of the out-of-the-box controls, but a clean way to do this might be to hold the values entirely client-side in JavaScript and then just posting them as arrays (or dynamically added form elements) and parsed server-side into the values needed for the database update.

Comment: Use the wizard control. Inside the wizard you can include and other list controls on some states.

Comment: What do you mean by the wizard control?

Comment: Went down the table route in the end